# Logical Structure (Example from Convergence of Sequences)

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, convergence-divergence

I'm new to mathematical logic and to real analysis. I have studied Daniel Velleman's How to Prove It and that's how I got my first experience with logical structures. Now, I'm studying real analysis (Abbot's Understanding Analysis) and I figure out that I did not grasp 100% of the concepts behind a logical structure when I was studying the convergence of sequences.

Therefore, I was wondering if someone can help me understand the fundamentals behind the logical structure that I present below. Let me show how I got there:

**Definition of Convergence of Sequence:** A sequence $({ a }_{ n })$ converges
to a real number $a$ if, for every positive number $\varepsilon$, there exists a $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\ge\Bbb{N}$ it follows that $\left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon$.

I translated this definition into a logical structure and I got the following:
$\left( \forall \varepsilon >0 \right) \left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \left( \forall n\ge { N } \right) \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon$

However, when I tried to write a formal proof for a simple convergence example, I noticed that I have to rewrite the logical structure like the one below so that I could follow what some authors call "The template for some proof".

So my question is: Why does the logical structure above can be translated to the one below? What concept and I missing? WHat should I now in order to understand this?
$\left( \forall \varepsilon >0 \right) \left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \forall n\left( n\ge N\Rightarrow \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon  \right)$

With my question in mind, I just want to show why am I focusing so much on transforming into this last logical structure. The reason why is because I can easily follow steps that usually help me prove things. (I have made a lot of progress since I learned about logical structures. When I was trying to study real analysis without it, I could not prove anything at all, just very simple things.)

So, let me give an example in case I had figured out the last logical structure at first. I would just do the following steps:

**Example**: Prove that lim$\left( \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)=0$

1) Write the "right" logical structure: $\left( \forall \varepsilon >0 \right) \left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \forall n\left( n\ge N\Rightarrow \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon  \right)$

2) Change the first parenthesis for: "Let $\varepsilon >0$ be an arbitrary positive real number". Then I would be left with: $\left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \left( \forall n\ge { N } \right) \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon$.

3) I learned that I need to pick just one good example for N in order to complete the proof. So, after some scratch work, I would say: "Choose a natural number $N$ satisfying $N>\frac { 1 }{ { \varepsilon  }^{ 2 } }$"

3) Now, I would change the "$\forall n$" for: "Let $n$ be an arbitrary natural number such that $n\ge { N }$. Thus, assume $n\ge { N }$".

4) Now, my goal would be to prove $\left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon$.

5) I would complete the proof and show that:
$n\ge N>\frac { 1 }{ { \varepsilon  }^{ 2 } }$ implies that $n>\frac { 1 }{ { \varepsilon  }^{ 2 } }$ which implies that $\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  } <\varepsilon$, which completes the proof.

Therefore, just because I was not able to (at first) note that $\left( \forall \varepsilon >0 \right) \left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \left( \forall n\ge { N } \right) \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon$ can be transformed into this $\left( \forall \varepsilon >0 \right) \left( \exists N\in { N } \right) \forall n\left( n\ge N\Rightarrow \left| { a }_{ n }-a \right| <\varepsilon  \right)$ it has prevented me from safely writing a proof for this example.

I know that I am a beginner and that mathematicians do not focus on the logical structures to prove things, but at least it has been helping me a lot.

Comment: (+1) Your steps are nicely explained! As for your actual question, most mathematicians proceed intuitively (in the way that @hamam_Abdallah explains), but if you had to fully justify the equivalence, then you'd need to use one or more identities among those listed under *Provable identities* at the Wikipedia page for [*First-order logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (or similar identities, as this is only a partial list of all such identities that one might intuitively use in mathematical proofs).

Answer (score 2):

When you write $$\forall n\ge N,$$

it is not rigourous.

You should write
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) : n\ge N$$

and the proposition $$\forall n\ge N \;\; |a_n-a|<\epsilon$$
becomes

$$\Bigl(\forall n\in \Bbb N \;\;:\; n\ge N\Bigr)\;\; |a_n-a|<\epsilon$$

which is logically equivalent to
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N \;\; (n\ge N \implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon )$$

The argument whose premisses are $$n\in \Bbb N \text{ and } n\ge N$$
and the conclusion $$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$$
is Valid.

Comment: Thank you very much. A simple answer that now made me understand. So, the only thing was that the second logical structure is **logically equivalent** to the first one. Okay, now I accept it. At the same time, is hard to only accept it, because as I beginner I tend to feel that it always has "to make sense", but actually is not sense that we are looking for, we are looking for a way to "logically prove things" using mathematical logical as the system of reference. Thanks!